# UIWebViewのConstrains制限の違和感

Tags: xcode, storyboard

XcodeでViewの上にUIWebViewを置いています。
画面いっぱいにUIWebViewを広げたく、Tailing Space, Leading Space, Bottom Space, Top Spaceの値をSuperview(view)から”0”に設定すると左右に空白が発生します。Tailing Space, Leading Spaceの値を”-16”にすると画面いっぱいになります。非常に違和感を感じます。これはpaddingか何かある状態なのでしょうか？通常の状態なのでしょうか？なぜ、このようなことになっているかわかりません。ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

マージンに設定された値を基準として使用するかどうか、AutoLayoutを指定する画面で設定出来るようになっています。

[image: 制約の対象をマージンにする]

チェックを付けた場合、-16で画面の端になります（モーダル表示した場合は変わってきますが）。チェックを外した場合、0が画面の端を表すようになります。

さらに細かい情報については、こちらが参考になるかと。

ios - What is "Constrain to margin" in Storyboard in Xcode 6 - Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807545/what-is-constrain-to-margin-in-storyboard-in-xcode-6